# Copy cell from Interactive Grid Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm trying to copy a specific cell from an Interactive Grid (which is in Display Only mode, if that matters), and instead of copying the cell I'm in, I'm copying the whole row. I can't seem to find any way to copy just the cell.

APEX versión: Application Express 19.1.0.00.15

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex does not enable copy functionality to interactive report by purpose.
To enable it, you need to use even handler for copy event. This handler should be on the body or document. It can be achieved through Dynamic Action :

Event: Custom
Custom Event: copy
Selection Type: jQuery Selector
jQuery Selector: body

Then add one JavaScript true action with below code:

```
var text, i, selection, gridSel;

var event = this.browserEvent.originalEvent; // need the clipboard event

// we only care about copy from a grid cell ignore the rest

if ( !$(document.activeElement).hasClass("a-GV-cell") ) {

    return;

}

var view = apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView"); //change "emp" to you IG static id

if ( view.internalIdentifier === "grid") {

    text = "";

    selection = window.getSelection();

    gridSel = view.view$.grid("getSelection");

    for (i = 0; i < gridSel.length; i++) {

        selection.selectAllChildren(gridSel[i][0]);

        text += selection.toString();

        if (gridSel[i].length > 1) {

            selection.selectAllChildren(gridSel[i][1]);

            text += " \t" + selection.toString();

        }

        text += "";

    }

    selection.removeAllRanges();

    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);

    event.preventDefault();

}
```

The above will copy the current grid selection to the clipboard when the user types Ctrl+C while in a grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder  if the below javascript can be modified in order to trigger 'toggle' actions of interactive grid such 'selection-mode'.

apex.region( "[region static ID] " ).call( "getActions" ).lookup( "[action name]" );

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, I managed to find the solution.
Go on **Interactive Grid's attributes--> JavaScript Initialization Code**
and add the following code that creates a button that copies the selected cell.

```
    function(config) {

  let $             = apex.jQuery,

toolbarData   = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(), 
toolbarGroup3 = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3");


    toolbarGroup3.controls.push({type: "BUTTON",
                        label: "Copy cell",
                        icon: "fa fa-copy is-blue",
                        iconBeforeLabel: true,
                        iconOnly: false,                       
                        disabled: false,
                        action: "custom-event" // instead of specific action eg "selection-copy", create a custom event
            });

    config.initActions = function( actions ) {

        actions.add( {

            name: "custom-event",

            action: function(event, focusElement) {
                actions.lookup('selection-mode').set(false); // select cell instead of the whole row
                apex.region( "users_id" ).widget().interactiveGrid( "getActions" ).invoke( "selection-copy" ); // copy the selection
                actions.lookup('selection-mode').set(true); // select again the whole row (important in case of master-detail grids)
            
            }

        } );

    }       


config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
  return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F8 to toggle between row-select and cell-select.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
    const activeElement = $(document.activeElement)[0];
    const textToCopy = activeElement?.innerText || window.getSelection();
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', textToCopy);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The idea is to add a Event Listener to the application where it selects the active element's text as text/plain. So, adding this code block to a page load dynamic action on global page should do the trick.
Hope it helps.